# Trouble installing ns-3 gym

Tags: python-3.x, openai-gym, ns-3

I am trying to learn to work on **ns-3 gym** , the framework which helps in integrating **openAigym** and ns-3, by following the steps given [here](https://github.com/tkn-tub/ns3-gym). But in the fourth step it says to install ns3gym from the src folder, the issue is that I'm not able to find the openaigym folder inside the src folder.

When I try to run the command it says not found.
Command used:

```
pip3 install ./src/opengym/model/ns3gym
```

The exact error displayed is:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: './src/opengym/model/ns3gym'
Hint: It looks like a path. File './src/opengym/model/ns3gym' does not exist.
```

It would be really helpful if someone could point the way or where i did wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enter the path correctly on your computer after downloading the package to install.

for example:

```
pip3 install C:/Users/user-name/Desktop/.../src/opengym/model/ns3gym
```

Install ns3gym ***located*** in src/opengym/model/ns3gym (Python3 required)